# Как переписать код, чтоб его можно было использовать в цикле?

Tags: javascript

```
var onLinedsasd=(async()=>{
  if(navigator.onLine){
    var date=+new Date();
    var res=await fetch('/favicon.ico?_='+date);
    var ret=await res.headers.get('Content-Type').split('/')[0]=='image';
  }else{
    ret=navigator.onLine;
  }
  return ret;
});
```

Хотелось бы переписать такой код xn, tu можно было использовать в условии цикла.
Например

```
if(onLinedsasd()){
//...
}else{
//...
}
```

Возможно ли это?

Comment: Просто добавьте await, не?

Comment: `onLinedsasd().then(res => { console.log(res)})` в res придет то что вернет функция после ее завершения